# How can I make the error message in a Rails 4.2 custom validator overridable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I have a custom validator. I want it to provide a useful default error message. But if the caller - a model - uses the :message argument to override the message, I want that to work. Unfortunately, I seem to be hard-coding my validation message into my custom validator and don't know how to make it more flexible.

Custom validator:

```
class EmailnessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  EMAIL_REGEXP = /some regexp/

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?

    unless value.match(EMAIL_REGEXP)
      record.errors.add(attribute, I18n.translate("validators.emailness.error", attribute: attribute))
    end
  end
end
```

Model that calls it:

```
validates :email, presence: true, emailness: {
  message: I18n.translate("my_model.email.emailness.error")
}
```

i18n:

```
validators:
  emailness:
    error: "This should only be a default error message"
my_model:
  email:
    emailness:
      error: "This is the error message I want"
```

Unfortunately, when I wire this up to a controller and a view, the error message I'm seeing is "This should only be a default error message" rather than "This is the error message I want".

How can I rewrite my custom validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because option `messages` was ignored in your model:

```
validates :email, presence: true, emailness: {
  message: I18n.translate("my_model.email.emailness.error")
}
```

You can merge `options` to solve your problem:

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  return if value.blank?

  unless value.match(EMAIL_REGEXP)
    record.errors.add(attribute,
      I18n.translate("validators.emailness.error", attribute: attribute))
      options.merge!(value: value)) # merge options that you passed
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! And as it turns out, this is down there in the nitty gritty of the canonical validation how-to at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html. I just missed it. Also worth pointing out that ```options``` isn't an argument to the ```validate_each``` method, but rather a method of ```ActiveModel::EachValidator```.

Comment: By the way, the way I ended up tackling this was slightly different: `record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || I18n.t("validators.emailness.error", attribute: attribute))`